# Is there a way to access the body of an iframe via JS after a document.write in the same?

Tags: javascript, iframe, document-body

The problem is with a backfill adunit. The script tag supplied uses document write to write itself in the code. I can't use this as is, as this is supposed to be used as a backfill if another adunit fails.
After pageload I am asynchronously loading and checking a VAST tag and if for some reason the VAST tag is invalid or whatever, the backfill script tag supplied should be used.

Obviously I can't write the supplied  tag in there with document.write as the whole content would be gone after the page was rendered and to div.innerHTML the tag is pointless as it doesn't run and even worse seems to use document.write in itself again. (not sure)

I now tried to put it into an iframe but the whole adunit size of the containing iframe is messed up, as the document.body has a margin of 8px per default.
So for instance a 300x250px adunit would have the 8px margin of the body of the iframe and the iframe inside a 300x250px adunit container and being 300x250px itself would get scrollbars.

I can easily get the body via `domObj.contentWindow.document.body.style.margin="0px"' however, after using document.write the style is gone, and even worse, I can't access the body anmore.

```
function addPassbackCode(iframe, code) {
    var iframeDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document; 
    console.log(iframeDoc);
    iframeDoc.open();
    iframeDoc.write(code);                    
    iframeDoc.close();     
    console.log(iframeDoc);
}
```

Above nicely outputs the `#document` twice.

```
function addPassbackCode(iframe, code) {
    var iframeDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document; 
    console.log(iframeDoc.body);
    iframeDoc.open();
    iframeDoc.write(code);                    
    iframeDoc.close();     
    console.log(iframeDoc.body);
}
```

This one outputs the `<body></body>` and `null`
I just assume that the script tag supplied to me uses document.write again, but does that make the body in the iframe inaccessible to me?

Is there any way to dynamically change the body's style inside the iframe after I added the  tag into it?
I hate iframes and barely to never use them but it seems the only way.
All should be done in good old plain JS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that at the time of `console.log()` the iframes' body simply isn't ready. Adding an `.onload()` eventhandler seems to fix that.

```
function addPassbackCode(iframe, code) {
    var iframeDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document; 
    console.log(iframeDoc.body);
    iframeDoc.open();
    iframeDoc.write(code);                    
    iframeDoc.close();     
    iframe.onload = function() {
        console.log(iframe.contentWindow.document.body);
    };
}
```